# Linux Traffic Control: qdisc mq

Tags: linux, networking, tc

On my Linux system I see this:

```
# ip link list
....
2: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
....
```

What's `qdisc mq`? In http://lartc.org/lartc.html I find only information about IMQ.

In the examples in the howto there are also `qdisc noop` and `qdisc noqueue`, but no details about them.

Comment: Check `man tc` for further information about 'queueing discipline'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A google search would have easily yielded [this article from the vger kernel mailing list](http://lwn.net/Articles/351021/):

> These patches contain a classful multiqueue ("mq") dummy scheduler to
> fix a couple of problems with the current multiqueue TC API
> integration. The changelogs of patch 05 and 07 contain more details.
>
> The mq scheduler does two things:
>
> - present device TX queues as classes, allowing to attach different qdiscs   to them, which are grafted to the TX queues
> - present accumulated statistics of all device queue root qdiscs
>
> Its used by default for multiqueue devices instead of the regular
> pfifo_fast qdisc, but can also be attached manually to restore
> multiqueue behaviour after attaching a non-multiqueue (shared) qdisc.

Multiqueue is a feature is otherwise referenced as RSS (Receive-Side-Scaling) which basically is distributing the load of packet processing among several cores. Further reading: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/networking/scaling.rst